# how to load js action on html of another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a scenario of two different files where I need to load one html in another.

iframe.html:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="flexselect">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
</select>
<iframe src="index.html" style="width:100%; border: 0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/flexselect.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/jquery.flexselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/liquidmetal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("select.flexselect").flexselect();
            });
    </script>           
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't show any error at the same time its not working too. What I have observed is that its not getting triggered on the select tag which is above the iframe tag.

It works if I keep the select tag content in the `index.html` page, but there the iframe is not allowing to display the full dropdown content. It is getting restricted to certain height & allowing to scroll.

So I can't keep select tag in the iframe, it should be out of the iframe.

How can we make it workable?

Comment: You are confusing will you be iframing even if you put the select on the index.html?

Comment: @snit80, Yes..iframe is must in my case. Situation is like I need to load the index.html file in another file, so I use iframe. But when I keep the select tag in iframe this is the issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39741412/jquery-chosen-content-not-getting-out-of-the-iframe-instead-scrolled-within-the)

Comment: Have you considered giving a height to the iframe?

Comment: @snit80 If I give height to the iframe..say 200px, it occupies the certain height just to display the drop down. On page load the user feels why this much space is been left blank. He will come to know that the space is given to show the dropdown only on click of the select tag, till then it looks blank

Comment: Ok, so why do you need it to be in the iFrame. The community can certainly help you out here. We just need to know what restriction you have and why you need the iFrame in the first place?

Comment: Purpose is to load another file which has css, js files in it & some other stuff, I have loaded that file using iframe tag. I tried to repalce iframe with object tag, even that behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should know , How communication between iframe and parent window works.
Below code you can use to call parent window method.

```
window.parent.functionName();
```

Comment: where you want me to keep this window.parent.functionName();

Comment: create function in iframe.html and call same function from index.html

Comment: this works (tested locally)..but not in my case..I can't write js code in the iframe.html :( It won't load javascript, that is a different story again :'(